# Number of ways of factoring a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am looking for an example of a finite group $G$ for which number of ways to factor it is very high. For example I can factor $C_{15} = C_3 \times C_5$. I am looking for an example of group for which number of ways of factoring that group is high. I want an example of group of size $n$ for which number of ways to decompose that are superpolynomial in $n$.

Comment: Do you know the classification of finitely generated abelian groups?

Comment: What is your definition of two factorizations being the same? Do you regard them as being the same if their factors are isomorphic, or do the direct factors need to be the same? For example, how many factorizations are there of $C_2^2$ of the form $C_2 \times C_2$? Is it just $1$, or is it $6$ (or possibly $3$ is you regard $A \times B$ as being the same as $B \times A$).

Comment: @ Derek Holt It will be 6.

Comment: Are you interested in decomposing $G$ as a direct product of two subgroups, or any number of them?  Either way, as @symplectomorphic is suggesting, the elementary abelian groups $(C_p)^r$ seem like a natural place to look.  Factoring this as a direct product of $r$ copies of $C_p$ is equivalent to choosing a basis for the $r$-dimensional vector space $(\mathbb F_p)^r$ (up to scaling each basis vector), and the number of choices is superpolynomial in $p^r$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $G = C_2^k$, which has order $n=2^k$. It has at least $2^{k^2/4}$ subgroups of order $2^{k/2}$ (let's suppose $k$ is even for simplicity), and each of those has a comparable number of complements, so we have $\Omega(2^{k^2/2}) = \Omega(n^{t\log n})$ factorizations for some $t>0$, which is superpolynomial in $n$.

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of the fact$^\dagger$ that $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_{mn} \iff \gcd(m, n) = 1$.  For intuition-building, let's suppose you have $\displaystyle n = \prod_k p_k$ for distinct primes $p_k$.  Count the number of ways you can distribute this collection of $p_k$ into "boxes" $\{B_j\}$ where each box gets at least one prime, and let $l_j$ denote the product of the primes in the box $B_j$.  Notice that the set of integers $\{l_j\}$ are mutually coprime, so given such a distribution, we can write $\mathbb{Z}_n \cong \displaystyle \prod_{j} \mathbb{Z}_{l_j}$.  In other words, there's a bijection between the number of distinct ways you can distribute those primes into boxes and the number of ways you can factor $\mathbb{Z}_n$.  Also, think about what you want "distinct factorings" to mean; this is to say, is $A \times B$ considered the same as $B \times A$?  Whether the answer is 'yes' or 'no' won't drastically change the above reasoning, but you'll want to take it into account.

Now generalize the idea for arbitrary $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

$^\dagger$From this fact quickly follows the more general statement $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_2} \times \cdots \times \mathbb{Z}_{n_k} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n_1n_2...n_k} \iff \operatorname{gcd}(n_k, n_j) = 1$ whenever $k \neq j$.   I provide a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1279829/why-isnt-mathbbz-2-times-mathbbz-30-isomorphic-to-mathbbz-60/1279851#1279851).  This helps motivate the [fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_abelian_group#Classification), which gives two "canonical" ways to express *finite* abelian groups in particular as a direct product of finite cyclic groups.